# Ajax + Rails not working on Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui, heroku

I have a pop-up sign-in form that has the error messages display in the body of the form via jQuery Ajax.  It works fine on my local environment (PostGresQL, WEBbrick) but not on Heroku.  On Heroku, the user is redirected to a new page which displays just the error message i.e., {"error":"Invalid Email Address: testing@test.com"}

There are actually two signup forms on the page, one that pops up via jQuery Dialog, and the other is embedded on the page.  Thanks for any help.

Here's the controller:
     class MailingListController < ApplicationController

```
 respond_to :json

 def create
   gb = Gibbon.new(Settings.mailchimp.api_key)
   res = gb.list_subscribe({:id => Settings.mailchimp.list_id, :email_address => params[:email]})
   if res == true
     render(:json => {:body => "okay"})
   else
     render(:json => {:error => res["error"]})
   end
 rescue
   render(:json => {:error => "Fatal Error"})
  end
end
```

Here's the js (I know, duplicate code, I'm just trying to get it to work):

```
  // Mailing List Watcher
 var mailingList2 = $("#mailing-list2");
 if ( mailingList2.length ) {
   mailingList2
     .live("completed", function(e){
     })
     .live("success", function(e){
       var that = this;
       $.cookie("mailingListSubmitted", "true", {expires: 7});
       if(mailingList2.find("#mailing-list2 #status2").length == 0){
         mailingList2
           .find("form input[type='text']")
           .after($("<div></div>").attr({id : "status2"}))
       }
       mailingList2
         .find("form input[type='text']")
           .attr("disabled", true)
           .fadeOut(5000);
       $("#mailing-list2 #status2")
         .text("Email submitted successfully!")
         .effect("highlight", { }, 1000);
     })
     .live("failure", function(e, error){
      if(mailingList2.find("#mailing-list2 #status2").length == 0){
         mailingList2
           .find("form input[type='text']")
           .after($("<div></div>").attr({id : "status2"}))
       }
       $("#mailing-list2 #status2")
         .text(error)
         .effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
     })
     .live("submittal", function(e, emailAddress){
       if ( emailAddress == "" || emailAddress == null ) {
         $(this).trigger("failure", ["You need to specify an email address!"])
         return false;
       }
       var token = $.token();
       $.post("/mailing_list", {email: emailAddress, authenticity_token: token}, function(response, status, xhr){
         if(response.error){
           $(mailingList2).trigger("failure", ["An error occurred: " + response.error]);
         } else {
           $(mailingList2).trigger("success");
         }
       }, "json")
       .error(function(){
         $(mailingList2).trigger("failure", ["An error occurred. Please try again in a few minutes."]);
       });
     });


   mailingList2.find("form").submit(function(){
     emailAddress = mailingList2.find("input[name='email']").val();
     $(mailingList2).trigger("submittal", [emailAddress]);
     return false;
   });

   var mlSetting = $.cookie("mailingListSubmitted");
   if ( mlSetting == "true" ) {
     mailingList2.remove();
   }
 }

 // Mailing List Watcher
 var mailingList = $("#mailing-list");
 if ( mailingList.length ) {
   mailingList
     .live("completed", function(e){
     })
     .live("success", function(e){
       var that = this;
       $.cookie("mailingListSubmitted", "true", {expires: 7});
       if(mailingList.find("#status").length == 0){
         mailingList
           .find("form input[type='text']")
           .after($("<div></div>").attr({id : "status"}))
       }
       mailingList
         .find("form input[type='text']")
           .attr("disabled", true)
           .fadeOut(5000);
       $("#status")
         .text("Email submitted successfully!")
         .effect("highlight", { }, 1000);
     })
     .live("failure", function(e, error){
      if(mailingList.find("#status").length == 0){
         mailingList
           .find("form input[type='text']")
           .after($("<div></div>").attr({id : "status"}))
       }
       $("#status")
         .text(error)
         .effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
     })
     .live("submittal", function(e, emailAddress){
       if ( emailAddress == "" || emailAddress == null ) {
         $(this).trigger("failure", ["You need to specify an email address!"])
         return false;
       }
       var token = $.token();
       $.post("/mailing_list", {email: emailAddress, authenticity_token: token}, function(response, status, xhr){
         if(response.error){
           $(mailingList).trigger("failure", ["An error occurred: " + response.error]);
         } else {
           $(mailingList).trigger("success");
         }
       }, "json")
       .error(function(){
         $(mailingList).trigger("failure", ["An error occurred. Please try again in a few minutes."]);
       });
     });


   mailingList.find("form").submit(function(){
     emailAddress = mailingList.find("input[name='email']").val();
     $(mailingList).trigger("submittal", [emailAddress]);
     return false;
   });

   var mlSetting = $.cookie("mailingListSubmitted");
   if ( mlSetting == "true" ) {
     mailingList.remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post a stack trace of the error? The error has more to do with your environment configuration rather than javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Your environments/production.rb is not configured properly to send email. You need to make sure that it is set up to send email as a domain you actually own. [Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) and [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp) both have good articles on the subject.

Comment: Actually, there are two almost identical signup forms on the same page, and the ajax works on one but not the other.  The one that doesn't work is in a jquery.ui dialog, but otherwise they are the same and both function on my local enviro.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here, and although I read this previously, it took a few attempts to get this to work: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#exporting-via-a-backup